# Center a form using Pure

Tags: css, html, forms

I am using Pure to style my html. But for some reason it is pushing my from all the way to the left of the page. How can I fix this.

Comment: The page at your link renders with everything aligned on the left.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Nope. I was just got my directions wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign a width or a max-width on the form and align it on the center of the screen. Try this class:

```
.myForm {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 768px;
}
```

And also assign the .myForm class to your form.